# Saving allowed positions from a 3x3 matrix

Tags: c#, unity3d

I wrote the next code chunk to save all the allowed positions from a 3x3 matrix, it's working but I think it could be better. Besides something similar happens in my Randomizer class, although I admit it's messy.

```
public class MatrixRegistry : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int matrixVolume;
    private int matrixCount;

    private GameObject[] matrix;

    private List<GameObject> dynamicCubes = new List<GameObject>();
    private List<Vector3> staticCubes = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<Vector3> allowedPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    public Func<List<GameObject>> GetDynamicCubes { get; private set; }
    public Func<List<Vector3>> GetAllowedPositions { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        #region Getting all Matrix Cubes

        matrixCount = gameObject.transform.childCount;

        if (matrixCount != 0)
        {
            matrix = new GameObject[matrixCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < matrixCount; i++)
            {
                matrix[i] = gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;

                if (matrix[i].GetComponent<CubeInfo>().cubeType == CubeSort.Dynamic)
                {
                    dynamicCubes.Add(matrix[i]);
                }

                if (matrix[i].GetComponent<CubeInfo>().cubeType == CubeSort.Static)
                {
                    staticCubes.Add(matrix[i].transform.position);
                }
            }
        }

        GetDynamicCubes = () => dynamicCubes;
        #endregion

        #region Setting Allowed Positions

        matrixVolume = 3; // Hard Coding

        for (int x = 0; x < matrixVolume; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < matrixVolume; y++)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < matrixVolume; z++)
                    {
                        Vector3 position = new Vector3
                        {
                            x = x,
                            y = y,
                            z = z
                        };

                        allowedPositions.Add(position);
                    }
                }
            }

        for (int f = 0; f < staticCubes.Count; f++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < allowedPositions.Count; a++)
            {
                if (allowedPositions[a] == staticCubes[f])
                {
                    allowedPositions.Remove(allowedPositions[a]);
                }
            }
        }

        GetAllowedPositions = () => allowedPositions;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Randomizer
{
    private MatrixRegistry matrixRegistry;
    private EventManager eventManager;

    public Randomizer(MatrixRegistry matrixRegistry, EventManager eventManager)
    {
        this.matrixRegistry = matrixRegistry;
        this.eventManager = eventManager;

        eventManager.OnStartGame += Randomize;
    }

    private void Randomize()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixRegistry.GetDynamicCubes().Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3
            {
                x = Random.Range(0, 3),
                y = Random.Range(0, 3),
                z = Random.Range(0, 3)
            };

            for (int j = 0; j < matrixRegistry.GetAllowedPositions().Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < matrixRegistry.GetDynamicCubes().Count; k++)
                {
                    if (randomPosition == matrixRegistry.GetAllowedPositions()[j])
                    {
                        if (randomPosition != matrixRegistry.GetDynamicCubes()[k].transform.position)
                        {
                            matrixRegistry.GetDynamicCubes()[i].transform.position = randomPosition;
                        }
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The randomizer class should check all the allowed positions to get in place all the cubes and avoid overlapping issues.
I know it's not the best, and this is why I'm here.

Comment: Why don't you post the complete class? I'd be much easier to review it having all the code rather then some _random_ snippets.

Comment: @t3chb0t I didn't think it was necessary, it's just a for loop, but already I did it.

Comment: It looks much better now and it's much easier to understand. Thanks for updating ;-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are checking if any allowedPositions are in the staticCubes list seems very inefficient to me.  I think it would be more efficient to check whether each position is in the staticCubes list as they are created then add them to the allowedPositions list.

Using a LINQ query for this wil also make it much more concise:

```
allowedPositions = (from int x in Enumerable.Range(0, matrixVolume)
                    from int y in Enumerable.Range(0, matrixVolume)
                    from int z in Enumerable.Range(0, matrixVolume)
                    let position = new Vector3(x, y, z)
                    where !staticCubes.Contains(position)
                    select position).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't know much about LINQ features, I'm going to read about it. About Randomizer class, the Randomize method could be improve using LINQ. I still think is awful.

Comment: @LobsangWhite - I added notes about the Randomizer class for you to look at.

Comment: Yes, but it's not swap among their own positions, it's a 3x3 matrix, that's means 27 positions, what it does is shuffle among all the possible positions, but the static ones.

Comment: @LobsangWhite - according to your code, the positions in dynamicCubes don't include the positions in staticCubes

Comment: Exactly, this is why I use GetAllowedPositions method, because I stored all the matrix positions there, except static cubes positions, and I check if the new position could be the right one if is equal to an allowed position from the list returned by GetAllowedPositions method.

Comment: @LobsangWhite -- If the dynamicCubes have the same positions as the allowedPositions, then I don't see the difference.

Comment: No, they are not, look in MatrixRegistry the way allowed positions, I store all 27 position and then I remove the static positions, maybe, you think the matrix is ​​full of cubes, dynamics and statics, but the matrix have spaces also, where the dynamic cubces moves.

Comment: @LobsangWhite - I made another attempt.

Comment: I'm sorry, could be the language barrier, I'm not a native english speaker, either way it doesn't work, they are overlapping each other.

Comment: @LobsangWhite -  I would suggest submit a new question for the randomizer class, but this time include what the allowedPositions would look like and what the dynamicCube positions would be before and after the randomizing.